# Let S a subspace of V and $T(S) = \{T(s)\mid s \in S\}$. Prove that $T(S)$ is a subspace of $\text{range}(T)$.

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, linear-transformations

On page 363, "Linear Algebra Step by Step", appears this exercise and I used the following chain of reasoning.

> 11. Let $T : V \to W$ be a linear transformation. Let S be a subspace of V and $T(S) = \{T(s)| s \in S\}$. Prove that T(S) is a subspace of range(T).

Take $T(u), T(v) \in T(S)$. Then, $u, v \in S$.

Show $kT(u) + cT(v) \in T(S)$.
\begin{align*}
    kT(u) + cT(v) & = T(ku + cv) && \text{[since T is linear]}
\end{align*}
Hence, $T(ku + cv) \in T(S)$ since $(ku + cv) \in S$ and S is closed under addition and scalar multiplication.

Is this proof correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, except that the first sentences are not quite correct. I would begin with “Take $s,t\in T(S)$. Then for sume $u,v\in S$, $s=T(u)$ and $t=T(v)$.”